# How do I execute a method only once in Android?

Tags: android

My problem is as follows:

- I have an end point, suppose `something.com/token`, to which I have to hit a *GET* request. From the response that I obtain, I would like to store it in some `String token`(This has to be done only **once** when I start my app)
- I want to hit another point, suppose `something.com/chat`, to which I have to pass my `token` to. In my layout, when I click a button - I want to `getText` from the `EditText` and call an Async task to which I will pass my `text` and `token`

I have been able to reach a stage in which I am able to hit both the requests multiple number of times. Hence, getting the `token` multiple times and passing it to my `something.com/chat` every time I click on the `button`

How do I call the first step only once and pass it to my `/chat` implementation

Comment: How about using shared preferences ?

Comment: ^ Yes, store a `boolean` value in [SharedPreferences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)

Comment: @codeMagic Don't need a boolean, just store the token

Comment: @cricket_007 good point. I was just thinking about as far as *"execute a method only once"* so that it would cover other situations,

Comment: you can do either way. But according to your question, Boolean will surely work out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this, by using `shared preferences`. Store a value in shared preferences:

```
SharedPreferences prefs  = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putBoolean("key",1); //or you can also use editor.putString("key","value");
editor.commit();
```

After doing so, say for example if user recalls an activity, then you check the value of in the shared prefs and if it is found, then just perform the action you wish to do else, allow the user to continue with the activity.

To retrieve values from a shared preferences file, call methods such as `getBoolean()` and `getString()`, providing the key for the value you want, and optionally a default value to return if the key isn't present.

Here is a quick reference:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!alreadyExecuted) {
    doTrick();
    alreadyExecuted = true;
}
```